# Undefined variable: allUsersData (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\plearning\resources\

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf

Hellow friends I am trying to generate pdf in laravel, i can view my data but can not generate pdf. what is the problem. please help me. My controller is given`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;
use Excel;
use View;
use Request;


class allUserPdfController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       return view('allUserPersonalCheckBox');
    }

    public function allUserPdf(Request $request)
    {

            $users = DB::table('users')->get();


            $allUsersData = array();

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $user_id = $user->id;

                $education = DB::table('education')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $publication = DB::table('publications')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $supervision = DB::table('supervisions')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $fyproject = DB::table('fyprojects')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();

                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);

                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }

             return View::make("pdf/allUserPersonalPdf")->with("allUsersData",$allUsersData);

    }


    public function allUserCheckBoxPdf(Request $request)
    {

            $users = DB::table('users')->get();


            $allUsersData = array();


            $per = Request::get('per');
            $edu = Request::get('edu');
            $pub = Request::get('pub');
            $sup = Request::get('sup');
            $fyp = Request::get('fyp');


            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $user_id = $user->id;

                $education = DB::table('education')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $publication = DB::table('publications')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $supervision = DB::table('supervisions')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
                $fyproject = DB::table('fyprojects')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();

            if($per && $edu && $pub && $sup  && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);         
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $pub && $sup ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);           
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $pub && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $sup && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per && $pub && $sup && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($edu && $pub && $sup && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $pub ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $sup ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per && $edu && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per  && $pub && $sup){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per  && $pub && $fyp){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'publication'=>$publication,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
             else if($per  && $sup && $fyp){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($edu  && $pub && $sup){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($edu  && $sup && $fyp){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($pub  && $sup && $fyp){
                $userAllData=array('publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per && $edu ){
               $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user, 'education'=>$education);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per && $pub ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'publication'=>$publication);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per && $sup ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($per && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($edu && $pub ){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'publication'=>$publication);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($edu && $sup ){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($edu && $fyp ){
                $userAllData=array('education'=>$education,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if(  $pub && $sup){
                $userAllData=array('publication'=>$publication, 'supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if(  $pub && $fyp){
               $userAllData=array('publication'=>$publication,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($sup && $fyp){
                $userAllData=array('supervision'=>$supervision,'fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($per){
               $userAllData=array( 'user'=>$user);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData); 
            }
            else if($edu){
               $userAllData=array('education'=>$education);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($pub){
                $userAllData=array('publication'=>$publication);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else if($sup){
                $userAllData=array('supervision'=>$supervision);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }

            else if($fyp){
                $userAllData=array('fyproject'=>$fyproject);
                array_push($allUsersData, $userAllData);
            }
            else {
                return view('pdf/personalpdf');
            }

            }

             //return View::make("pdf/allUserPersonalPdf")->with("allUsersData",$allUsersData);
           //  $pdf = PDF::loadView("pdf/allUserPersonalPdf")->with("allUsersData",$allUsersData);
           // return $pdf->stream('allusersinfo.pdf');
             $pdf = PDF::loadView("pdf/allUserPersonalPdf", compact('"allUsersData",$allUsersData'));
                return $pdf->download('personalinfo.pdf'); 

    }




    // public function allUserPdf(Request $request)
    // {
    //         $userInfo = DB::table('users')->get();
    //         $education = DB::table('education')->get();
    //         $publication = DB::table('publications')->get();
    //         $supervision = DB::table('supervisions')->get();
    //         $fyproject = DB::table('fyprojects')->get();


    //         $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/allUserPdf', compact('userInfo','education','publication','supervision','fyproject'));
    //         return $pdf->stream('allUserinfo.pdf'); 

    //         return view('pdf/allUserPdf');
    // }

    function excel(){
        $userInfo = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();
        $userArray[]= array('name','fname','phone','email','off_email');
        foreach ($userInfo as $user) {
            $userArray[] = array(
                'name'   => $user->name,
                'fname'   => $user->fname,
                'phone'   => $user->phone,
                'email'   => $user->email, 
                'off_email' => $user->off_email,
            );

        }
        Excel::create('User Info', function($excel) use ($userArray)
        {
            $excel->setTitle('User Info');
            $excel->sheet('User Info', function($sheet) use ($userArray){
                $sheet->fromArray('$userArray',null,'A1',false,false);
            });
        })->export('xlsx');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}`
```

And here is my view code. I can view the result in simple view but I have problem in pdf generation. It gives me the error  Undefined variable: allUsersData (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\plearning\resources\views\pdf\allUserPersonalPdf.blade.php).

Here is the code of my view file where I can see the result.

```
@extends('layouts.style')
@section('content')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>All Users Data</h1>

  @if(count($allUsersData) > 0)

    @foreach($allUsersData as $usersData)

      <div class="container">

      @php
      $user = isset($usersData['user']) ? $usersData['user']  : '' ;
      @endphp

      @isset($user)
      @if(!empty($user))
          <h2 class="text-success text-center">Profile</h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>father Name</th>
            <th>contact</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Official Email</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->fname}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->phone}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->off_email}}</td>
            </tr>

          </table><br>
        @endif
      @endisset


      @php
      $userEducation = isset($usersData['education']) ? $usersData['education']  : '' ;
      @endphp

      @isset($userEducation)

        @if(!empty($userEducation))
          <h2 class="text text-success text-center">
          Education Details
          </h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
            <tr>
            <th>
            Degree
            </th>
            <th>University</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Research Area</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($userEducation as $value)
              <tr>
              <td>{{$value->degree}}</td>
              <td>{{$value->univ}}</td>
              <td>{{$value->country}}</td>
              <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
              <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach

          </table><br>
        @endif
      @endisset

      @php
      $userPublication = isset($usersData['publication']) ? $usersData['publication']  : '' ;
      @endphp

      @isset($userPublication)
        @if(!empty($userPublication))

        <h2 class="text text-success text-center">
        Publications Details
          </h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
          <tr>
          <th>
          Title
          </th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach($userPublication as $value)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$value->title}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->status}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach

        </table><br>

        @endif
      @endisset

      @php
      $userSupervision = isset($usersData['supervision']) ? $usersData['supervision']   : '' ;
      @endphp

      @isset($userSupervision)
        @if(!empty($userSupervision))
          <h2 class="text text-success text-center">
          Supervisions Details
          </h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
          <tr>
          <th>
          Student Name
          </th>
          <th>Semester</th>
          <th>Research Area</th>
          <th>Course Work</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach($userSupervision as $value)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$value->sname}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->semester}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->cwork}}</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach

        </table><br><br>
        @endif
      @endisset

      @php
      $userFyproject = isset($usersData['fyproject']) ? $usersData['fyproject'] : '' ;
      @endphp



      @isset($userFyproject)

        @if(!empty($userFyproject))
        <h2 class="text text-success text-center">
        Fyprojects Details
        </h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
          <tr>
          <th>
          Degree
          </th>
          <th>Groups Name</th>
          <th>Project Title</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach($userFyproject as $value)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$value->degree}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->gname}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->ptitle}}</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach

        </table><br>


        @endif

      @endisset

      </div>

    <hr><br>
    @endforeach
  @else
    <h2>No Data Found</h2>
  @endif


</body>
</html>
@endsection
```

Comment: Your compact is off. Try `$pdf = PDF::loadView("pdf/allUserPersonalPdf", compact('allUsersData'));`

Comment: It works, thanks alot

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)